# Encountering time out error in the middle of a matplotlib for loop

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, timeout

I have a code which will go through three dictionaries, and make some plots if the keys all match. I've been running into an odd issue due to the use of the matplotlib table.

When I first got this code to run,  I had no issues finishing the whole loop. Now I am encountering a time out error by the second iteration

I tried moving the the table out of the for loop. 
I added plt.close('all')
I also try importing matplotlib again at the end of the loop in hopes of resetting something in the backend.

```
for k, v in oct_dict.items():
    for k2, v2 in stu_dict.items():
        for k3, v3 in oct2_dict.items():
            if k == k2 and k == k3:
                with PdfPages('{}.pdf'.format(k)) as pdf:
                        #rc('font', **{'family': 'serif', 'serif': ['Computer Modern']})
                        #v = v[v['a_1920'] != 0]
                    rc('text', usetex=True)
                    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,10.5))
                    gs=GridSpec(2,2) # 2 rows, 3 columns
                    ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
                    ax0.bar(x=np.arange(2), height = [float(v['a_1920'])*100, mean_a_1920*100], color = nice)
                    plt.xticks(np.arange(2), ['{}'.format(k), 'D75'])

                    for p in ax0.patches:
                        a =p.get_height()
                        ax0.annotate('{:0.2f}'.format(float(a)), (p.get_x()+.1, p.get_height() * .75), weight = 'bold')
                    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])


                    c = str(len(v2['student_id']))
                    c2 = int(v['c_1920'])
                    props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='white', alpha=0.0)
                    c3 = int(v['b_1920'])
    # place a text box in upper left in axes coords
                    c4 = int(v['d_1920'])
                    ax1.text(0.0, 0.95, 'Number of  Age : {}'.format(c3), transform=ax1.transAxes, fontsize=12,
                                    verticalalignment='top')

                    ax1.text(0.0, 0.85, 'Number of Incomplete : {}'.format(c2), transform=ax1.transAxes, fontsize=12,
                                verticalalignment='top')
                    ax1.text(0.0, 0.75, 'Number of Invalid : {}'.format(c4), transform = ax1.transAxes, fontsize = 12,
                              verticalalignment = 'top' )
                    ax1.text(0.0, 0.65, 'Number of who will reach Age:\n{}'.format(c), transform=ax1.transAxes, fontsize=12,
                                 verticalalignment='top' )

                        #ax1.table(cellLoc = 'center', cellText = [] , loc = 'upper center')

                    ax1.axis('off')
                    ax1.axis('tight')
                        #fig.suptitle('Monthly Summary', va = 'top', ha= 'center')
                    fig.text(0.3, 1, 'Monthly Summary '+ dt.date.today().strftime("%b %d, %Y"),  fontsize=12, verticalalignment='top', bbox=props)
                        #plt.subplots_adjust(top = .75)
                        #plt.tight_layout()
                        #gs.constrained_layout()
                        #print(float(v3['inc']))
                        #print(float(v3['com']))
                    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,0])

                    plt.sca(ax2)
                    p1 = plt.bar(np.arange(1), int(v3['com']), width=.25,color = 'b',label = 'Complete')
                    p2 = plt.bar(np.arange(1), int(v3['inc']), width = .25, bottom = int(v3['com']), color = 'r', label = 'Incomplete')
                    plt.legend()
                    for p in ax2.patches:

                        ax2.annotate((p.get_height()), (p.get_x()+.1, p.get_height() * .75), weight = 'bold')
                    ax2.set_xticks([])
                      # # #ax2.set_xlabel='Students Who Will Turn 15'
                    ax2.set_title('Students who will turn 15 later in the school year')
                    ax2.set_xticks([])
                    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,1])
                    a = int(v3['com'])+int(v3['inc'])


                    ax3.axis('off')

                    plt.tight_layout()
                    pdf.savefig()
                    plt.close('all')  
                    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,11.5))
                    gs=GridSpec(1,1) 
                    axs = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
                    cell_text = []
                    v2 = v2.drop(['Grand Total','birth_dte','loc'],axis = 1)
                    binarymap = {0:'No',1:'Yes'}
                    v2['Plan Not Complete'] = v2['Plan Not Complete'].map(binarymap)
                    v2['Plan Already Complete'] = v2['Plan Already Complete'].map(binarymap)
                    labels = [six column titles here]
                    for row in range(len(v2)):

                        try:

                            cell_text.append(v2.iloc[row])
                        except:
                            pass

                    table = axs.table(cellLoc = 'center', cellText = cell_text, colLabels = labels,
                                      rowLoc = 'center', colLoc = 'center',loc = 'upper center',fontsize = 32)
                    table.set_fontsize(32)
                    table.scale(1, 1.5)
                            #axs.text(0.0,0.5,'For the column')
                    axs.axis('off')
                    pdf.savefig()
                    #plt.savefig('{}_list.pdf'.format(k))
                    plt.show()
                    plt.close('all')
                    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

TimeoutError: Lock error: Matplotlib failed to acquire the following lock file:
    C:\Users\myusername.matplotlib\tex.cache\23c95fa5c37310802233a994d78d178d.tex.matplotlib-lock

NOTE: If some of the key names dont match in this code it is on purpose, I had to change them up for this post since it is public. The error is thrown by the second iteration once the code reaches the axs.table line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got everything to run properly after using the conda command prompt to clean the environments

conda clean --all

Something that works but I would have liked to avoid was just removing the use of tex for this script. rc param tex set to False, code finished running pretty quickly as well